# How to draw number into circle shape?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I am trying to draw the numbers into circle shape.

But I did not succeed. I have tried some tutorials which are available but could not succeed.

We haven't fixed the numbers to show in circle. Numbers are dynamic.

I am  attaching snapshot below so that I could clear what I am really trying to do.

Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Concatenated transforms will be your friend for a task like this. Start by looking at all the `CGAffineTransform...` methods.

Comment: Position a bunch of labels in the center and rotate + translate them. Just be aware that order does matter, i.e. rotate+translate ≠ translate+order.

Answer (score 2):

You could use David's suggestion of placing labels by translating and rotating them. That would be easiest, but would involve a fair amount of overhead.

Alternatively you could use CoreText to draw your text along a CGPath that's a circle. Erica Sadun's excellent "iOS Developer Cookbook" series includes a recipe that shows how to wrap text along a curved path using Core Text. I don't remember which volume it's in however.

A third option would be to use Nick Lockwood's excellent iCarousel framework to create a circular carousel out of the numbers you're using. It is very flexible and you should be able to adjust the settings to get a look very similar to the control you've posted.